# Script do not stop only Keyboard

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Hi all i have a keyboard G105
i trying to make a litle script, ist working but it dont want to stop.
I will like to G1 on and G2 off. thx

```
**Macro LIST**

  

     skill Selfbuff -- use after any playmacro "Petx" after reuse time
     1 PlayMacro(selfbuff1) Sleep (1800000) --30 minutes
     2 PlayMacro(selfbuff2) Sleep (600000) -- 10 minutes
     -- add more
     

     Skill Empower -- use after any playmacro "Petx" if none of then are 
  runing, can be at same time with  "Skill Sellbuff" list

       1 PlayMacro(Boost1) Reuse time = 480 seconds,Boosting time = 60 seconds
       2 PlayMacro(Boost2) Reuse time = 600 seconds, Boosting time = 180 seconds
       -- add more


  -- G1 = 2pet
  -- G2 = 3pet

 local function interruptable_sleep(delay)
   local tm = GetRunningTime() + delay
   repeat
      if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then return true end
      local t = tm - GetRunningTime()
      if t > 0 then Sleep(math.min(t, 100)) end
   until t <= 0
 end

 function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event=="G_PRESSED" and arg==1 then
      repeat
         local exit
         for _, phase in ipairs{
            {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, },
            {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
            {macro = "Pet1",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
         -- if  on reuse PlayMacro(selfbuff1),PlayMacro(Selfbuff2), may add more
         -- if  on reuse PlayMacro(boots1),PlayMacro(boost2) may add some
            {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, },
            {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
            {macro = "Pet2",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
         -- if  on reuse PlayMacro(selfbuff1),PlayMacro(Selfbuff2), may add more
         -- if  on reuse PlayMacro(boots1),PlayMacro(boost2) may add some
            {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, },
            {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
         } do
            PlayMacro(phase.macro)
            exit = interruptable_sleep(phase.sleep_macro)
            AbortMacro()
            if exit then break end
         end
      until exit
      PressAndReleaseKey("scrolllock")
   end
 end
```

I really appreciate your help, but I can't understand well,
I think the explanation from before has not been enough
I know I don't understand much about programming but something I came to understand

This is my full script thaks to you

```
local function interruptable_sleep(delay)
local tm = GetRunningTime() + delay
 repeat
  if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then return true end
  local t = tm - GetRunningTime()
  if t > 0 then Sleep(math.min(t, 100)) end
until t <= 0
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
 if event=="G_PRESSED" and arg==1 then
  repeat
     local exit
     for _, phase in ipairs{
        {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, },
        {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
        {macro = "Pet1",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
        {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, },
        {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
        {macro = "Pet2",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
        {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, },
        {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
     } do
        PlayMacro(phase.macro)
        exit = interruptable_sleep(phase.sleep_macro)
        AbortMacro()
        if exit then break end
     end
  until exit
    Sleep(250)
  PressAndReleaseKey("scrolllock")
  elseif event=="G_PRESSED" and arg==2 then
  repeat
     local exit
     for _, phase in ipairs{
        {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, },
        {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
        {macro = "Pet1",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
        {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, },
        {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
        {macro = "Pet2",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
        {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, },
        {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
        {macro = "Pet3",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
        {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, },
        {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
     } do
        PlayMacro(phase.macro)
        exit = interruptable_sleep(phase.sleep_macro)
        AbortMacro()
        if exit then break end
     end
  until exit
    Sleep(250)
  PressAndReleaseKey("scrolllock")
  elseif event=="G_PRESSED" and arg==3 then
  repeat
     local exit
     for _, phase in ipairs{
        {macro = "Basicos1",    sleep_macro = 13000, },
        {macro = "Pick",        sleep_macro = 1000,  },
        {macro = "PetLargo1",   sleep_macro = 2800,  },
        {macro = "Basicos1",    sleep_macro = 13000, },
        {macro = "Pick",        sleep_macro = 1000,  },
        {macro = "PetLargo2",   sleep_macro = 2800,  },
     } do
        PlayMacro(phase.macro)
        exit = interruptable_sleep(phase.sleep_macro)
        AbortMacro()
        if exit then break end
     end
  until exit
    Sleep(250)
  PressAndReleaseKey("scrolllock")
  elseif event=="G_PRESSED" and arg==4 then
  repeat
     local exit
     for _, phase in ipairs{
        {macro = "Basicos1",    sleep_macro = 16000, },
        {macro = "Pick",        sleep_macro = 2000,  },
        {macro = "PetLargo1",   sleep_macro = 2800,  },
        {macro = "Basicos1",    sleep_macro = 16000, },
        {macro = "Pick",        sleep_macro = 2000,  },
        {macro = "PetLargo2",   sleep_macro = 2800,  },
        {macro = "Basicos1",    sleep_macro = 16000, },
        {macro = "Pick",        sleep_macro = 2000,  },
        {macro = "PetLargo3",   sleep_macro = 2800,  },
        {macro = "Basicos1",    sleep_macro = 16000, },
        {macro = "Pick",        sleep_macro = 2000,  },
     } do
        PlayMacro(phase.macro)
        exit = interruptable_sleep(phase.sleep_macro)
        AbortMacro()
        if exit then break end
     end
    until exit
    Sleep(250)
    PressAndReleaseKey("scrolllock")
    elseif event=="G_PRESSED" and arg==5 then
    repeat
     local exit
     for _, phase in ipairs{
        {macro = "Basicos1",    sleep_macro = 16000,},
        {macro = "Pick",        sleep_macro = 500,},
     } do
        PlayMacro(phase.macro)
        exit = interruptable_sleep(phase.sleep_macro)
        AbortMacro()
        if exit then break end
     end
    until exit
    Sleep(250)
   PressAndReleaseKey("scrolllock")
  end
 end
```

Is made for diferents spot at game for auto farming

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Comment: the API manual does not list any function to poll the current status of the G keys. You only get a pressed and released event. But as you're processing the pressed event you cannot get another event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I will like to G1 on and G2 off.

IMO, it's impossible to stop your script with G2 or G1.
But you can use ScrollLock key to stop the script:

Initially the ScrollLock LED is off.
You press G1, the script starts.
While the script is running, you press ScrollLock, its LED turns on.
The script finishes its work and turns the ScrollLock LED off.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event=="G_PRESSED" and arg==1 then
        repeat
            for _, Fkey in ipairs{"F1", "F2"} do
                PlayMacro("Basicos")
                for t = 1, 20 do
                    Sleep(1000)
                    if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then break end
                end
                AbortMacro()
                PressAndReleaseKey(Fkey)
                if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then break end
                Sleep(1500)
            end
        until IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")   -- is ScrollLock LED on?
        PressAndReleaseKey("scrolllock")  -- turn it off
    end
end
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
local function interruptable_sleep(delay)
   local tm = GetRunningTime() + delay
   repeat
      if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then return true end
      local t = tm - GetRunningTime()
      if t > 0 then Sleep(math.min(t, 100)) end
   until t <= 0
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event=="G_PRESSED" and arg==1 then
      repeat
         local exit
         for _, phase in ipairs{
            {macro = "Basicos", sleep_macro = 13000, fkey = "F1", sleep_fkey = 2000},
            {macro = "Basicos", sleep_macro = 15000, fkey = "F2", sleep_fkey = 1800},
            {macro = "BUFF",    sleep_macro = 5000,  fkey = "F3", sleep_fkey = 2500},
         } do
            PlayMacro(phase.macro)
            exit = interruptable_sleep(phase.sleep_macro)
            AbortMacro()
            if exit then break end
            PressAndReleaseKey(phase.fkey)
            exit = interruptable_sleep(phase.sleep_fkey)
            if exit then break end
         end
      until exit
      PressAndReleaseKey("scrolllock")  
   end
end
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

```
-- G1 = 2pet
-- G2 = 3pet

local function interruptable_sleep(delay)
   local tm = GetRunningTime() + delay
   repeat
      if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then return true end
      local t = tm - GetRunningTime()
      if t > 0 then Sleep(math.min(t, 100)) end
   until t <= 0
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event=="G_PRESSED" and arg==1 then
      repeat
         local exit
         for _, phase in ipairs{
            {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, },
            {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
            {macro = "Pet1",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
            {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, },
            {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
            {macro = "Pet2",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
            {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, },
            {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  },
         } do
            PlayMacro(phase.macro)
            exit = interruptable_sleep(phase.sleep_macro)
            AbortMacro()
            if exit then break end
         end
      until exit
      PressAndReleaseKey("scrolllock")
   elseif event=="G_PRESSED" and arg==2 then
      local loop_ctr = 0
      repeat
         local exit
         loop_ctr = loop_ctr + 1
         for _, phase in ipairs{
            {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, skip_on_first_loop = false, },
            {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  skip_on_first_loop = false, },
            {macro = "Pet1",     sleep_macro = 2000,  skip_on_first_loop = false, },
            {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, skip_on_first_loop = false, },
            {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  skip_on_first_loop = false, },
            {macro = "Pet2",     sleep_macro = 2000,  skip_on_first_loop = false, },
            {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, skip_on_first_loop = false, },
            {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  skip_on_first_loop = false, },
            {macro = "Pet3",     sleep_macro = 2000,  skip_on_first_loop = false, },
            {macro = "Basicos1", sleep_macro = 16000, skip_on_first_loop = false, },
            {macro = "Pick",     sleep_macro = 2000,  skip_on_first_loop = false, },
         } do
            if loop_ctr > 1 or not phase.skip_on_first_loop then
               PlayMacro(phase.macro)
               exit = interruptable_sleep(phase.sleep_macro)
               AbortMacro()
               if exit then break end
            end
         end
      until exit
      PressAndReleaseKey("scrolllock")
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfect,
I don't know about programming
I've been reading the forum for a couple of hours and I got my first script done, but no one said about the G keys that I couldn't stop a script
Many thanks,
a doubt, if you don't mind
Is there a way for the script to stop immediately, without having to finish the loop ???

Comment: Thx for the help. need to be able to change sleep time between

Comment: Tnx for u help ,u are the master

Comment: Sorry master i am so noob i coud not modify the one u create for mi ,, can u check if i dont it ringht ,, thx

Comment: See `UPDATE #2`

Comment: let me abuse you a little more :). In the game I have several skills with different delays and time running, is there any way to make it use them after each Pet if it is in reuse? and if it is not in reuse, continue.
let's say the skills I have to press "Alt + 1" delay 480seconds sleep 1 minute "Alt + 2" and so on. I addede skill list at f. Thx a lotisrt post

Comment: In other words, you want some macros to run only when on the 2nd, 3rd,... loops but not on the first loop (they should be skipped on the first loop)?

Comment: See 3pet code in "update #2".  Set `skip_on_first_loop = true` where needed.

Comment: Why not make a macro for "Alt+A" and use it the same way as other macros in the script?  What means `Delay 480 secons Sleep 60 secons`?

Comment: Empower Skill  is something that boost my character, It has duration and reuse time, reuse time = Delay duration time = sleep. Yes i was thinking o make another macro with presskey"Alt+a" but if one of this macro  is running i will like to not use another, but keep runing but keep  runing Basicos ,Pet, and Pick

Comment: Thanks sorry for my inglish, if you dont feel like, dont worry , u done a great job with my srcipt , it work perfect i can live without we try to do

Comment: You can run these `Alt+a/b/c/d` skills separately (without pressing G1 and G2).  How the script would know whether they are running now or not?  GHUB can't run as a keylogger, it doesn't know which letters you have pressed.

Comment: ahh !!! ok , so is perfec like it is like now thax for all